# Handle Reset for specific field formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, react-select

I am new to react and I have just started using Formik
I like how simple it makes making forms and handling forms in react.
I have created multiple custom fields using formik, I am putting the react-select field I created as an example here.

```
import { ErrorMessage, Field } from "formik";
import React from "react";
import Select from 'react-select'

const SelectInput = (props) => {

  const { label, name, id,options, required, ...rest } = props;
  const defaultOptions = [
   {label : `Select ${label}`,value : ''} 
  ]
  const selectedOptions = options ? [...defaultOptions,...options] : defaultOptions
  return (
    <div className="mt-3">
      <label htmlFor={id ? id : name}>
        {label} {required && <span className="text-rose-500">*</span>}
      </label>
      <Field
        // className="w-full"
        name={name}
        id={id ? id : name} 
      >
          {(props) => {
          return (
            <Select
              options={selectedOptions}
              onChange={(val) => {
                props.form.setFieldValue(name, val ? val.value : null);
              }}
              onClick = {(e)=>{e.stopPropagation}}
              {...rest}
              // I want someting like onReset here
            ></Select>
          );
        }}
      </Field>
      <ErrorMessage
        name={name}
        component="div"
        className="text-xs mt-1 text-rose-500"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SelectInput;
```

This is the usual code I use for submitting form as you can see I am using resetForm() method that is provided by formik, I want to attach the reseting logic in on submit method itself.

```
  const onSubmit = async (values, onSubmitProps) => {
    
    try {
      //send  request to api
      onSubmitProps.resetForm()
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response.data);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Hi, what do you want to achieve exactly ? Reset only one field ?

Answer (score 2):

So if I understood you correctly you want to reset a specif field value `onSubmit` rather than resetting the whole form, that's exactly what you can achieve using `actions.resetForm()`.

> ***Note:** If `nextState` is specified, `Formik` will set `nextState.values` as the new "initial state" and use the related values of `nextState` to update the form's `initialValues` as well as `initialTouched`, `initialStatus`, `initialErrors`. This is useful for altering the initial state (i.e. "base") of the form after changes have been made.*

You can check this in more detail [here](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#resetform-nextstate-partialformikstatevalues--void).

And [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-brattain-70n92c?file=/src/App.js) is an example of resetting a specific field using `resetForm()` whereby you can see as you input name, email and upon submit only email field will get empty using `resetForm`.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
import { Formik } from "formik";

const initialState = {
  name: "",
  email: ""
};
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>My Form</h1>
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialState}
      onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
        console.log(values, "values");
        actions.resetForm({
          values: {
            email: initialState.email
          }
        });
      }}
    >
      {(props) => (
        <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={props.handleChange}
            onBlur={props.handleBlur}
            value={props.values.name}
            name="name"
          />
          <br />
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={props.handleChange}
            onBlur={props.handleBlur}
            value={props.values.email}
            name="email"
          />
          <br />
          <br />
          {props.errors.name && <div id="feedback">{props.errors.name}</div>}
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  </div>
);
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reset the selected value after the form is submitted, you need to provide a controlled `value` for the `Select` component.
The Formik `Field` component provides the `value` in the `props` object, so you can use it.

For example:

`SelectInput.js`

```
import { ErrorMessage, Field } from 'formik';
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

const SelectInput = ({ label, name, id, options, required, ...rest }) => {
  const defaultOptions = [{ label: `Select ${label}`, value: '' }];
  const selectedOptions = options ? [...defaultOptions, ...options] : defaultOptions;

  return (
    <div className='mt-3'>
      <label htmlFor={id ? id : name}>
        {label} {required && <span className='text-rose-500'>*</span>}
      </label>
      <Field
        // className="w-full"
        name={name}
        id={id ? id : name}
      >
        {({
          field: { value },
          form: { setFieldValue },
        }) => {
          return (
            <Select
              {...rest}
              options={selectedOptions}
              onChange={(val) => setFieldValue(name, val ? val : null)}
              onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
              value={value}
            />
          );
        }}
      </Field>
      <ErrorMessage name={name} component='div' className='text-xs mt-1 text-rose-500' />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SelectInput;
```

and `Form.js`

```
import { Formik, Form } from 'formik';
import SelectInput from './SelectInput';

function App() {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        firstName: '',
      }}
      onSubmit={async (values, { resetForm }) => {
        console.log({ values });
        resetForm();
      }}
    >
      <Form>
        <SelectInput
          name='firstName'
          label='First Name'
          options={[{ label: 'Sam', value: 'Sam' }]}
        />
        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
      </Form>
    </Formik>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Therefore, if you click the `Submit` button, value in the `Select` component will be reset.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a useRef hook to the Fromik component and then reset the form within the reset function without adding it as a parameter to the function.

https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_useref.asp
It's one of the really nice hooks you'll learn as you progress through React :)